# How to intercept UI routes in Angular for user session management?

Tags: http, angular-router

We have an angular application with node as the back end. We have an authenticate server where session management is done. There is a http interceptor that we are using in order to check whether a session is live in order to execute the http request. If the session has expired we navigate to Login page. And this works for most of the pages as we have some or the other http request in ngOnInit and hence they work fine. But I want to know how to intercept when there are no http requests on load. How do I encounter this? Should I use canActivate? Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [canActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) hook of the Angular Router for doing this. You don't want to repeat the login check code in every component, canActivate can by reused in other parts of the application in the router config declaration. You can also check if the user has permissions to see this page.

What you can also do is to make the request and wait for the response, if the response is 403 the [HTTP Interceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) routes back to the Login page.

If you don't want to check every time, you can use [local storage](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html5_webstorage.asp) to save the start session date and check if that is expired.